# Parallellising a for loop for a function with multiple inputs and outputs

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've read several posts on multiprocessing in Python, but it's not clear to me how can I use them for my problem (where I have multiple inputs and outputs). Most of the available examples consider a single output function with a rather simple structure.

Here is the code in Python:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
i1 = np.random.random(n)
i2 = np.random.random(n)
i3 = np.random.random(n)
i4 = np.random.random(n)

o1 = np.zeros(n)
o2 = np.zeros(n)
o3 = np.zeros(n)

def fun(i1,i2,i3,i4):
    o1 = i1 + i2 + i3 + i4
    o2 = i2*i3 - i1 + i4
    o3 = i1 - i2 + i3 + i4

    if o1 < o2:
        o1 = o2
    else:
        o2 = o1

    while o1 + o2 > o3:
        o3 = o3 + np.random.random()

    return o1,o2,o3

for i in range(n):  # I want to parallellise this loop
    o1[i],o2[i],o3[i] = fun(i1[i],i2[i],i3[i],i4[i])
```

I am only looking for a way to parallelize the `for` loop. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I assume you want `multiprocessing.Pool` with `map()` applied

Comment: You could bundle your inputs into a single object (e. g. a list or a dictionary) and do the same for the output. That way you can treat your problem as being with single input and output.

Comment: @RaJa Can you tell me how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use a generator to combine your input lists i1 to i4. Your math-function `fun` will return a list-object. Now I have a single argument as input (the generator) and get a single object as output (the list). I have tried the code below and it works.

You can add a sleep-command in your `fun`-function to see the speed-gain when using multiple processes. Otherwise your `fun`-function is too simple to really benefit from multi-processing.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

n = 1000
i1 = np.random.random(n)
i2 = np.random.random(n)
i3 = np.random.random(n)
i4 = np.random.random(n)

def fun(a):
    o1 = a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3]
    o2 = a[1]*a[2] - a[0] + a[3]
    o3 = a[0] - a[1] + a[2] + a[3]

    if o1 < o2:
        o1 = o2
    else:
        o2 = o1

    while o1 + o2 > o3:
        o3 = o3 + np.random.random()

    return [o1,o2,o3]

# a generator that fills the Pool input
def conc(lim):
    n = 0
    while n < lim:
        yield [i1[n], i2[n], i3[n], i4[n]]
        n += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = conc(n)
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(fun, numbers))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the procedure you defined can be considered to be generic, for these types of functions that require quite some time to compute for one iteration?

Comment: I usually use this scheme when using queues. I don't use `pool.map` as I am missing flexibility. But I would assume that this could be defined as generic.